# идентичность бесконечных циклов while и for

Tags: java, while

1.)

```
while (true)
System.out.println("C");
```

2.)

```
for (; true; )
System.out.println("C");
```

Почему эти бесконечные циклы идентичны, ведь у for после первого разделительного знака  ;  идет указание до какого значения продолжается цикл? Этот цикл бесконечный, потому что по умолчанию значение boolean false? и поэтому пока не будет true, будет продолжаться данный цикл? Тогда почему while сразу считается true, а не false? Спасибо.

Comment: `for( действия_перед_началом_цикла; условие_для_продолжения_итераций_цикла; действие_в_конце_каждой_итерации)` так выглядит синтаксис оператора `for`, `условие_для_продолжения_итераций_цикла` всегда равно `true`, поэтому и цикл бесконечен.

Comment: Это в паскакале for работает со значениями. А в java нет никаких значений: ни начальных, ни конечных, ни шага цикла. Есть действие, которое выполняется при входе в цикл, условие для продолжения цикла, и действие, выполняемое в конце каждой итерации.

Comment: Считайте, что for это другой способ написания while, в одном операторе совмещающий, то что обычно выполняют для инициализации цикла (до оператора while), условие while, и действия в конце блока while. Если что-то из этого делать не надо, то на соответствующей позиции пустота, как в Вашем примере.

Answer (score 2):

> Почему эти бесконечные циклы идентичны, ведь у for после первого разделительного знака `;` идет указание до какого значения продолжается цикл?

Нет, в цикле for после первого разделительного знака `;` идет условие продолжения цикла. Да, обычно там стоит оператор сравнения - что задает конечное значение переменной цикла, но это лишь один из вариантов.

В данном случае там стоит `true` - то есть условие продолжения цикла всегда истинно. Потому цикл и получается бесконечным.

Кстати, есть еще более короткая форма бесконечного цикла:

3.)

```
for (;;)
  System.out.println("C");
```

Здесь отсутствие условия обрабатывается специальным образом.

Answer (score 0):

Есть хороший ответ в английском stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880870/java-for-vs-whiletrue.
Автор говорит, что никакой разницы нет между этими циклами. И показывает пример байт-кода c помощью плагина в Eclipse.